# Load string from input to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying out some things and am wondering if you can pass the string/text from an input into a span element inside an h2 with JQuery.

The HTML:

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns small-centered name">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name-text" placeholder="What's your name?" autocomplete="off" class="text-center">
    </div>
</section>
<section class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns small-centered name">
        <input name="submit-button" id="submit-button" type="submit" placeholder="button">
    </div>
</section>
<h2 class="third">Hi <span id="name-value"></span></h2>
```

The JQuery:

```
<script>
    var nameValue = $("name-text").val();
    $("#submit-button").submit(function () {
        $("#name-value").text(nameValue);
    });
</script>
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

*EDIT: Just wanted to say sorry if this has been added already. If so, I couldn't find it.*

Comment: check if the selector of `name-text` input is correct: in your post it is written without `#`, but it should be `$("#name-text")`.

Comment: @andreivictor : beat me by 7 seconds!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the identifier for HTML `id` in your jQuery code

```
var nameValue = $("name-text").val();
```

should be

```
var nameValue = $("#name-text").val();
           /*      ^^missed */
```

**Update**

your are trying `submit` on `input type` instead of `form`, try using `click` handler instead and wrap it inside that event :

```
$("#submit-button").click(function () {
    $("#name-value").text(nameValue);
    var nameValue = $("#name-text").val();
    alert(nameValue);

});
```

[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2pfwk86v/)

Comment: Wauw, embarrassing! Well, I tried it, but still doesn't show. Tried changing .submit to .click. Didn't work either

Comment: @Mowinckel : no issues...even best people face these problems at some point...:) have you included the jQuery library file before this piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot # character in your script.

```
    var nameValue = $("#name-text").val();
    $("#submit-button").submit(function () {
        $("#name-value").text(nameValue);
    });
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mu4o2sak/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the value of your input field at the time the form is submitted.
Because if you assign the value of the input to the nameValue variable outside of the submit function, you assign the value that is set at the beginning to the variable and not the current value.

But the submit event will only work if there is a form element around your input field and the submit button.

```
$("#submit-button").submit(function () {
    var nameValue = $("#name-text").val();
    $("#name-value").text(nameValue);
});
```

Comment: haven't thought about this. extended the answer with a hint about a required form.